# AS400 query column headings

Tags: db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

I don't know how to get in an Excel query the column headings when I query a DB2 table using Excel and ODBC on windows 10.

We are running on IBM iSeries System 7.1.

If I connect with ODBC, what I get is all column heading encoded like:

```
COS395  Is Company Name
COS357  Is Company address
COS381  Is Company telephone
```

I don't know if I'm making a mistake during query setup or whatever.

Thanks
Marcos

Comment: Are the `COS3##` values column names? You may be able to try the Excel Plugin from IBM i Access, but I don't know if that works with Windows 10.

Comment: What is the SQL query you're executing? The snippet of output you provided doesn't make sense for any typical ODBC or SQL query, whether against DB2 or otherwise.

Comment: Are you talking about column /descriptions/, or column /headings/? These are two different things generated by different DDS keywords; column /headings/ are, as far as I am aware, not really SQL constructs at all. But I agree with the others, we need to understand your situation far better before we can attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

To get ***nice*** looking IBM I headings into excel.  Create a view over the table *(pf)* with a quoted column names then query the view in excel.  Excel will use the quoted names for the column headings.  Nice.

```
create view mylib/myview as 
select COS395  as "Company Name"
, COS357  as "Company Address"
, COS381  as "Company Telephone"
from mylib/mfile
```